# Wordpress AJAX and AddToAny plugin

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, wordpress

I want to reload my Wordpress AddToAny plugin after http.get response in my Angular file. I read official documentation for this plugin. It says I need to use

```
a2a.init('page');
```

to reload it. In Angular I have this code

```
 $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/get-posts-by-ids?ids=' + "").success(function (res) {
        $scope.cars = res;
        console.log($scope.cars); // returns Array of objects
        $scope.isLoading = false;
        $timeout(function(){
            console.log( a2a.init('page')); // returns undefined
            a2a.init('page');
        },3000);
    });
```

In PHP file I'm using AddToAny shortcode to assign result of shortcode to Response that I'm retrieving in Angular

```
 $postsData[] = array(
    "title" =>$post->post_title, 
    "link" => get_permalink($post->ID), 
    "comment_count" => $post->comment_count,  
    "thumbnail"=>wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),  
    'car-thumbnail' ), 
    "addtoany"=>do_shortcode('[addtoany]'), // returns HTML markup fo AddToAny without any data
    "procent" => $procent, 
    'opinions_rate' => $rate_opinion, 
    "year" => $year
);
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $postsData; // this goes to Angular Response "$scope.cars = res;"
```

**My question is how to make it work with the Ajax, I can't get rid of AJAX, it has to be.**